# use xcom pull to retrieve the variables pushed from other dag

Tags: python, airflow

I am very much new to airflow and using "xcom_push" and "xcom_pull" function.

I have two dags d1 which has task t1 and second dag d2 with task t2 .

Now i am pushing the values from dag d1 using:

```
kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='start_date',value=start_date)
kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='end_date',value=end_date)
```

and pulling the same start_date and end_date in dag d2 using :

```
start_date = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(dag_id = 'd1', task_ids='t1',key="start_date")
end_date = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(dag_id = 'd1', task_ids='t2' , key="end_Date")
```

However getting "NONETYPE"error during xcom_pull.Can anyone please help me how can i pull the values from dag d1 into the dag d2

Comment: Seems like you have a typo on the 2nd `key` param of `xcom_pull`. Have you tried editing that one? In my experience, as long as the key you create in `xcom_push` is unique, it would always find it in `xcom_pull` even without the other params.

Comment: @jayg_code:Yeah i have corrected the typo.Can you please suggest if i need to include execution date as well ??

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass additionally param `include_prior_dates=True`, so that it would check XCom from previous dates.

> :param include_prior_dates: If False, only XCom from the current
> execution_date are returned. If True, XCom from previous dates
> are returned as well.

in your case looks like that:

```
start_date = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(dag_id = 'd1', task_ids='t1',key="start_date", include_prior_dates=True)
end_date = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(dag_id = 'd1', task_ids='t2' , key="end_Date", include_prior_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you having anything actually set the xcom variables?

Try the dags below:

d1

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'znovak',
    'email': ['me@me.com'],
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 11, 4)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='d1',
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None
    )

###############################
##### Create DAG Parameters ###
###############################
def set_xcom_params(**kwargs):
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='start_date',value=start_date)
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='end_date',value=end_date)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t1',
    python_callable=set_xcom_params,
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True
    )
```

d2

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'znovak',
    'email': ['me@me.com'],
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 11, 4)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='d2',
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None
    )

def pull_xcom_params(**kwargs):
    start_date = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(dag_id='d1',task_ids='t1',key="start_date")
    end_date = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(dag_id='d1',task_ids='t1',key="end_date")
    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t2',
    python_callable=pull_xcom_params,
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True
    )
```

Comment: this will not work.It is expecting execution date as well

Comment: @aspire you can set another xcom variable to be the current timestamp, and then pull that down.

Comment: @Zack can you please edit above answer with working one. How to incorporate that execution date please.

Answer (score -1):

XCOM's are used to exchange information between tasks of a single Dag.
The use case where you would like to retrieve output of a Dag for another Dag can be accomplished by storing the results in a file/database and proceeding accordingly.